# How to check my smtp( for gmail ) code is working in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, gmail

I m using smtp setting send e-mail in codeigniter

```
 //smtp settings  
        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
        $config['smtp_user'] = '****@*****.***';
        $config['smtp_pass'] = '*****';
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->from('*****@*******.****', '******');
        $this->email->to('******@********.****');
        $this->email->subject('email subject ');
        $this->email->message("my email messages");
        if($this->email->send()){
            echo "done";
        }
```

i) I m getting '**Done**' message.

ii) Getting e-mail on receiver e-mail  **($this->email->to('****@****.****'); )**

But I am not getting any notification in my smtp gmail account(inbox/sent).

How can i make sure that smtp is working ?

Comment: you are working locally ?

Comment: Try  $this->email->send();

echo $this->email->print_debugger();       Are you working on localhost and what exact message do you've on the screen after this.

Comment: no i m working on live server

Comment: Now a days google is not allowing to send an email using password. Check your email

Comment: if you are in liver server just keep the smtp host as localhost. remove remaining configurations this will work automatically

Comment: i think gmail have some authentication process , i did it before with core php (long ago )

Comment: why you want to go gmail. if you have live server then you have your own SMTP. Remove your configurations then try mine

Answer (score 0):

Create email.php file in application/config/ folder in live server

Location: application/config/email.php

```
<?php

/*
* Protocol name TROFEO SOFTWARE SOLUTIONS
*/
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';   

/*
* smtp_host name for mail sending.
* this 
*/

 //developers server name for smtp host
 $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';

//smtp port
 $config['smtp_port'] = 587;

//smtp user
$config['smtp_user'] = '******@***.**';

//smtp password
$config['smtp_pass'] = '************';

/*
*mail type send to user
*/
$config['mailtype']="html";

/*
* Character set of the mail
*/
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';

/*
*Wordwrap flag of the mail
*/
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

/*
New line character
*/
$config['newline']= "\r\n";
```

Then in your controller

```
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->from('*****@*******.****', '******');
    $this->email->to('******@********.****');
    $this->email->subject('email subject ');
    $this->email->message("my email messages");
    if($this->email->send()){
        echo "done";
    }
```

Comment: i just want to do it with smtp ( acc. to client )

Comment: try this configuration now

Comment: if i use your code than are you sure i will get confirmation mail on gmail account  to enable the service .

Comment: you can send email via Google SMTP server what ever you want you can send